# Time complexity for constructing a Python list from a dict

Tags: python, dictionary, time-complexity

I am trying to find the best way ( the most efficient in terms of time complexity ) to pop the last key-value pair in a Python dictionary.

What I am currently using is

```py
my_dict.pop(list(my_dict.keys())[-1])
```

But I am not sure what is the time complexity of `list(my_dict.keys())`
as I am trying to keep it `O(1)` on average

Comment: What is "the last key-value pair"? Why do you want to do that? The problem is not the .keys(), if anything the conversion to a list is the problem.

Comment: You won't know which one is the last one until you go through all the keys. Maybe there's a way to get it from the dict keys iterator itself, although probably not. I'll look. But making a list of it completely rules that out. You've already executed O(n) at that point, before you access [-1]

Comment: The definition of *last* in a dictionary is not very meaningful.

Comment: Thomas Weller makes a good point. If you care about retrieving items by index, maybe dict isn't the right data structure for you. But in the spirit of answering the question, all I've found so far is class dict_keys, which may be a PyListObject in the C interface, but is not a list, and """ D.keys() -> a set-like object providing a view on D's keys """ If there is a way, it is probably implementation specific.

Comment: `dict` won't let you do this in O(1).  Have you looked at `OrderedDict`?  https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict.popitem

Comment: What's wrong with [`my_dict.popitem()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.popitem) (it is LIFO)?

Answer (score 0):

> *What's wrong with [`my_dict.popitem()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.popitem) (it is LIFO)?* - [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75849296/time-complexity-for-constructing-a-python-list-from-a-dict#comment133791128_75849296) by [Timus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14311263/timus)

It [has O(1) time complexity](https://thecodingbot.com/python-dictionarys-popitem-method-with-examples/#:%7E:text=Time%20Complexity:) [due to being a [LIFO](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lifo-last-in-first-out-approach-in-programming/) operation] like you want.

Comment: Your reference for O(1) doesn't exist anymore. Do you have another?